# Gruntjs cwd mask

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My file structure:

```
services/
-- service1/
---- service1.png
-- service2/
---- service2.jpg
-- service3/
---- service3.gif
...
```

I use grunt-contrib-imagemin for minify and move images.

I want get this structure:

```
logo/
-- service1.png
-- service2.jpg
-- service3.gif
...
```

In my grunt-config I tried using '**' in cwd param, but it not work:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    imagemin: {       
        dynamic: {
            options: {   
                optimizationLevel: 3
            },      
            files: [
            {
                expand: true, 
                cwd: 'services/**/',
                src: ['*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'logo/'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  imagemin: {       
    dynamic: {
      options: {   
        optimizationLevel: 3
      },
      expand: true,
      flatten: true, 
      cwd: 'services',
      src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
      dest: 'logo/'
    }
  }
});
```

`cwd` is just a file path and doesn't do pattern matching. The `flatten` option will flatten your file output.

Comment: Tnx for answer, but your config create this files:

logo/service1/service1.png instead logo/servicce1.png